# ListView crashes when selection is switched fast

Tags: windows-8

i use a ListView to display a Selection, when switching through the possibilities with some time between the slections everything works fine, but when I switch fast (less then 1s) it crashes. The error I get is within the file "app.g.i.cs".
Sender is the app, the error is "{"Value does not fall within the expected range."}"
Thank you
(I've already cleaned and rebuild the project, didn't help)

Comment: > @SLaks questionary.exe!questionary.App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__1(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Zeile 50 + 0x20 Bytes C#

Comment: @SLaks I have never written the AnonymouseMethod_1, must be one that is automaticly generated